# MS SQL and my need for a little direction

Tags: sql-server

I've been lurking around for several weeks and have been totally blown away by the amount of information and how the community quickly responds. I have noticed that questions like this typically receive sarcastic remarks and sometimes get down voted. Please bear with me as I attempt my first post :)

I little background..
I work at a tiny software company as the "QA department". Our application has a MS SQL back to store customer data and short term loan information for financial service companies. I started working here 6 years ago as a gernal technician to provide support for their call center, so I've been overly exposed to SQL and have become fairly familiar with working with it. You probably wouldn't pay me to develop a enterprise level database, but at this point I've become familiar enough to do most things in SQL.

Why I'm asking my question..
I want to develop an application to store and track our software issues and new dev. I've done research on this website along with asking around and I still feel sort of lost as to which direction I should take. I want the core of the application to be pretty basic at first, to provide various screens between my entities/modules and to create reports to show their various relationships. In the future I want it to be more complex, to provide a web portal of some sort and to start getting into various complex QA software concepts. I've read around and it sounds like I might want some variation of C/VB for the windows portion, but all of the topics have sort of overwhelmed me. Do I want to start with a more basic one that was created 20 or 30 years ago? (I think that's C and C++, right?) or a more recent one like C#? Will I be able to develop a web portal with both of these? (by web portal I'm thinking it would provide access to our database of defects and have username/password sign-in). I've seen that the various .NET languages lean more towards web development, should I start with one of these?

I am at the very beginning of this and I fully understand that I'm jumping into some deep waters here. I want to make sure I don't end up spinning my wheels and that I focus my energy on something that won't end up being a bad idea in 1 or 2 years after I start. So far I've found this website very helpful, if I can pick a direction I know I won't have any problems finding what the next step is. It might help to know that I have no formal or informal programming background (if it wasn't obvious). I'm a 27yo techie who is starting his first venture into programming, go easy on me! Thanks for taking the time to read this :)

Comment: I'm confused as to what exactly you want to accomplish. If you're asking which language to use that's going to be closed as both duplicated and subjective/argumentative most likely. If you were clearer with your requirements this might be okay on Programmers.SE.

Comment: I'm looking for someone to read everything I said and to process it in a way to point me in a direction. I'm not nessecarly looking for which language to use, but more of the opinion from someone who has been in my shoes. What did they did when they first started and which things helped (including language). It seemed that my question was relative, if not I'm sorry. Please tell me where I might go :)

Comment: @Fuzzy: I did read everything you wrote. I see a bunch of him and haw concepts of "well we'd like something like this...". You don't come out with a complete question, and that makes it hard to determine what you want. If you want a language recommendation, you're going to have to get more concrete requirements first. We can't speculate about a project for which the requirements are not specified.

Comment: I don't know what you mean as concrete requirements, in my mind I feel like I haven't gotten that far. In the body of my post I listed a two or three basic concepts of my design, thats about as far as I got. I need something that I can build a base on and will allow me to grow. thats it :( [edit] and thanks for commenting!

Comment: @Fuzzy: Nobody is going to be able to give you a good answer for a language without a spec. I'm sorry, but there's no way around that. If you start trying to build something without even knowing what you want, how will you know where to start? That doesn't make any sense. (For what it's worth, for the basic stuff you're talking about I'd strongly recommend just going and getting an off-the-shelf tool like Team Foundation Server or FogBugz/Kiln, but given that I don't know exactly what you want I can't be sure.

Comment: I'm guessing this endeavor is mainly a learning experience that someone else won't be paying for.  I'd hope this is done on personal time. If it's not then i'd suggest (as others have stated) to learn how to setup an off the shelf solution.

Comment: @Used, yes this is a personal project. They are all for me learning things that help me do my job, but I don't think this is what they would have in mind haha.

Comment: @Billy - The answer from Mozillanerd was a good example of what I'm looking for. The vague referance to Team Foundation and FogBuz sounds like what I looking for too. The project I'm starting will likely be very losely definded for quite some time so I'm afraid I cannot provide any more details than I already have. Thanks for the questions, I hope they help explaining what I'm after.

Comment: @Fuzzy: That's not a good answer.

Comment: @billy - I'm not sure if you are being vague as an attempt to help me realize the flaws of my original post, or if you are attempting to train wreck the comments section and frustrate me. Either way, thanks for asking your questions. I'll try one more time... Mozilla may or may not have a good answer, who am I to say? I was simply trying give you an example so that you may have an idea of what I'm after. I don't want my comment to come off as rude, I'm trying to be as direct as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that your intent is to learn and create something yourself I think you should consider a LAMP stack and PHP with one of the PHP frameworks on top (Cake PHP, code-igniter or the like).

The C++ route is a long hard way (C++ is my language of choice) to learn; as a learning experience I think you will get quicker and more satisfying results with PHP.

I also think that this is a realistic project for someone of your skills over a period of a 6 to 12 months - start with a simple requirement and then build it up to have all the features you need.

If you just want a bug tracking system obviously there are many options that won't demand any development.

Comment: Thanks for the info! you and everyone else have helped alot!

Answer (score 2):

I won't recommend that you go to C, C++, or VB. C and C++ are used mainly for developement of system software, compilers, etc. VB is deprecated by now; there is a .net version VB.NET, but my preference is C#.

Looks like you are a Microsoft shop. Steer youself towards using C#. Visual Studio provides great support for development of Web Applications with support for holding state in entities backed by MS SQL.
I would start with a simple example as given in MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410597.aspx.

This example uses an Model View Controller based framework that is fairly easy to configure and use. They have great examples.

There is a free framework that also supports MS SQL Entity store http://www.coderun.com/ide/

Enjoy

Comment: I think this is great advice and a very fitting answer. I'd suggest C#/MSSQL as well. I've also given that exact walkthrough recently to a new intern. My additional advice is to now start coding with a clear objective in mind. To quote my old mentor: "You'll learn the best through need".

Answer (score 2):

Don't write a line of code. There are literally hundreds of open source and commercial software packages that already do what you want to do.  You'd be better of spending time researching them and finding the package that most closely meets your requirements.  A good solution will also be extensible enough that you'll be able to modify it to meet all of your requirements.

Since you work for a small company I can guarantee you that using your limited development hours "writing your own" will be counterproductive. You'd be better off adopting something off the shelf and becoming proficient at it.  You'll learn more about developing systems like this once you've become intimately familiar with one of them.

Check out JIRA or
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_issue_tracking_systems for some other ideas.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've spent a pretty decent amount of time researching QA and related software. I'm open to the idea of using an open source package that I could modify, but I'd rather step through the entire dev process. I'm looking to make this a learning experience and would like to develop something from the ground up. thanks for the wiki link!

Comment: @Fuzzy You can take open source system's source code and use it as your release 1 - load into source version control system and start developing your release 2. You will start learn development process immediatly. Otherwise you'll spend much time learning many near-development questions. If you want to learn architectures and languages open source system will be very good starting point - you will work in a virtual team. In other words, if you like to make automobile from the beginning by yourself this is one point. But if you want to learn mechanics to become engineer this is another point.

Comment: @Serg I think my original post might have been misleading, I'm probably not ready to take on C# quite yet. I will most likely take on an open source package if I end up making a windows app at all. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 1):

For the benefit of your company I would recommend to use an existing
solution.  But if you want to learn and build something of your own, I
would suggest that you check out some popular [web application
frameworks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application_framework), like:

1. [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/)
2. [Ruby On Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/)
3. [Zend](http://framework.zend.com/)

Good Luck with your project!

Comment: yes, I agree. Your suggestion (and everyone else who suggested similiar things) seems to be the best option for me! Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

How much experience do you have with things like installing Linux, Apache, Mysql, etc?  If you are completely new to this, then this will be a much tougher task, because there are many layers you'll have to learn before you can even get to the point of writing an end-to-end application.

I would avoid C/C++/C# because there are a lot of things you would need to learn about basic programming before you even got to the stage where you could make database calls.

On the assumption that you don't have experience with LAMP (Linux/Apache/Mysql/(Perl/Python/PHP)), my suggestion would be to start simply, by using a scripting language like Python or Perl.  You can very easily get a database connection, and start writing queries, and extracting data from there.  If you are used to Windows, I would install ActivePerl or ActivePython, and start from there.  You can start building a command line program that does what you want, and then from there, you can move on to creating a web application that can do something similar.

Building a web application would likely be much easier than writing a Windows application, so after you have gotten comfortable with the scripting language, that's the direction I would go afterwards.

Good luck!

Comment: I could install SQL and support a fully functional company, I have also create websites. I have been creating stored procedures for our applications for quite some time and feel like I can a pretty strong grasp of sql. websites arent exactly a strong point of mine. thanks for the advice.